# Solr Cloud querying across multiple collections

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is it possible to query across multiple collections, while running in SolrCloud mode and get general scoring?

Comment: Scoring is generally always per core; so that depends on what you mean by general scoring?

Comment: With global search I meant the score that will be calculated for all collections at once and not for each separately, but now as far as I understood it is impossible. I did not understand what is meant by score per core. So the score is calculated not even within one collection or shard, but exactly at the level of cores in SolrCloud mode?

Comment: A shard is _a core_, so the score is calculated based on the documents on that specific node; at least that was how it used to work, and I haven't seen any changes to that limitation - if it didn't you'd effectively have to exchange token counts for all matching documents across the whole, complete collection, which seems like it wouldn't really scale appropriately. But as long as you accept that, you can create a collection alias to search across multiple collections transparent to the caller.